# Bug in iOS coredata objectWithID when moving objects between contexts

Tags: ios5, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am observing a weird bug in iOS using core-data.
Basically, my setup is as follows-
Have 2 NSManagedObjectContexts, `tempContext` and `mainContext`.
I use `tempContext` as a temporary 'scratchpad' for creating and editing entities, and when I want to save them, I move it to the `mainContext` to save.
Note that `mainContext` is not the parent of `tempContext`.

The move happens as follows-

```
[1] newEntity.property1 = @"SomeProperty";
    newEntity.managedObjectContext // this is tempContext currently
[2] saveEntityInTempContext
[3] newEntity = (Entity *)[mainContext objectWithID:newEntity.objectID];
[4] [mainContext insertObject:newEntity];
```

Now, after insert[4], if I check `newEntity.property1`, it is set as `nil`.
However, if I check the property first after [3] and then after [4], it shows it correctly as "SomeProperty". I don't understand how forcing faulting should make a difference here.

My goal is just to move an entity from one context to another.

Comment: `[mainContext objectWithID:newEntity.objectID]` returns an object from the main context. I think it is not necessary (and probably wrong) to call `insertObject` on that object, it is already inserted.

Comment: How did you create `newEntity` in the first place? Is it already inserted into `tempContext`? Also, have changes been saved on `tempContext` when this code executes?

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes, ```newEntity``` is already inserted in ``tempContext``` and step[2] is to indicate that the entity is saved in ```tempContext```.

Comment: @MartinR Even without the insert, the problem exists (different behavior between entities explicitly faulted and not faulted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the immediate cause is, but it's almost certainly a weird side effect of an unnecessary step that really doesn't make any sense. I'm kind of surprised you don't get an exception in the last step.

Specifically, step #4 is completely unnecessary. Once you finish step #3, you have an instance that was loaded from `mainContext`. You don't need to do anything more at that point. It doesn't make sense to call `insertObject` for an object that you just looked up from the same managed object context.

Assuming that `tempContext` and `mainContext` use the same persistent store coordinator, the life cycle of this object proceeds as follows in your steps:

1. `newEntity` is already created but not saved. `tempContext` knows about `newEntity` but the data store does not (and of course `mainContext` doesn't know about it).
2. After saving, the data store has a record of `newEntity`. `newEntity`'s object ID changes to a permanent value.
3. As a result of your `objectWithID:` call, the instance of `newEntity` gets replaced with a different instance that was looked up via `mainContext`. It's attributes match the ones you created in step 1 and saved to the data store in step 2, because they were loaded from the data store.
4. Calling `insertObject` serves no purpose-- because the new `newEntity` you got in step 3 was looked up from `mainContext`, meaning that `mainContext` already knows about it. This is where I would have expected an exception. No exception occurs, but the call still doesn't make sense.

So, I'd just drop step #4 and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks, this line is what helped me solve the problem! "call, the instance of newEntity gets replaced with a different instance that was looked up via"